# Find the same elements in C-struct

Tags: c++, struct, element

I have to write a function that will add elements to C-struct, but it can't add the same element. Example:
Input:
`1 2 1 3`

Output:

```
ADDED 1
ADDED 2
NOT ADD 1
ADD 3
```

Elements are taken from array, here's piece of code that uses the function I need to write:

```
int tab[] = {1,4,1,3,5};
Node* head = 0;
for (size_t i = 0, e = std::size(tab); i != e; ++i) {
    bool b = add(head,tab[i]);
    cout << tab[i] << (b ? "     " : " NOT ")
         << "added" << endl;
}
```

C-struct `Node` looks like that:

```
struct Node {
  int   data;
  Node* next;
};
```

Here's what I wrote, but it adds all elements from array. I can't change the loop, only `add` function:

```
bool add(Node*& head, int data){
    Node *n = new Node;
    n->data = data;
    n->next = 0;

    if(!head)
        head = n;
    else{
        Node *tmp = head;
        while(tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = n;
    }
};
```

Comment: What you need to do is change your `add` code so that if first looks for the element in the list, using a loop, and only add it if it doesn't find it. This seems like an obvious thing to do, which part are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't know how to iterate through the list to find the same element

Comment: What exactly is your question? There is no question in your question post. Side note: there is no need for the `if` in `add`, you can do `while(head) head = head->next;`.

Comment: @Mrfk You are already iterating through the list in the `else` block. Within the `while` block, simply check the value of `tmp->data` and if it's the same as `data`, abort the operation.

Comment: It's a simple loop, `Node *tmp = head; while (tmp) { if (tmp->data == data) { found it } tmp = tmp->next; }` It does seem easier than the code you've written already but I guess pointers are difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the side note, I'll change that. My question is: How to iterate through Node elements to find if there are the same elements

Comment: You're missing the return values of `add`. Turn on **all** warnings for your compiler, it will help you find that kind of mistakes.

Comment: @WernerHenze Are you sure?

Comment: Thanks guys, I know what to do now. I will rewrite the function so it makes more sense

Comment: @Mrfk warning, don't get the wrong answer lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently you just add the element without looking if it is already present or not

The definition can be something like

```
bool add(Node*& head, int data){

  if(!head) {
    head = new Node;
    n->data = data;
    n->next = 0;
    return true;
  }

  Node *tmp = head;

  while (tmp->next) {
    if (tmp->data == data)
      return false;
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
  if (tmp->data == data)
    return false;

  tmp->next = new Node;
  tmp->next->data = data;
  tmp->next->next = 0;
  return true;
}
```

---

I encourage you to add a constructor to not have to set the data and next fields each time after you create a new instance

Exemple

```
Node::Node(int d) : next(0), data(d) {
}

// add should be a static method of Node, to be able to access next and data while they are private
bool add(Node*& head, int data){
  if(!head) {
    head = new Node(data);
    return true;
  }

  Node *tmp = head;

  while (tmp->next) {
    if (tmp->data == data)
      return false;
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }

  if (tmp->data == data)
    return false;

  tmp->next = new Node(data);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but no, I can't add the same data

Comment: I supposed only the result is relevant, I edited my answer to not add if already present

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I must say: that `add` function does too many things. Since we're doing C-isms: there should be a `Node* node_new(int)`, a `bool node_isNil(Node*)`, a `Node* node_last(Node*)` and a `bool node_find(int)`.

Comment: Should be `while (tmp)` not `while (tmp->next)` as it won't find the element that is last in the list.

Comment: @john no, the while search for the last element to add the new one after it, with `while(tmp)` how can you add the new element at the end of the list ?

Comment: @bruno You are right you can't add a new element with a loop like `while(tmp)` but you can't search the entire list with a loop like `while(tmp->next)`. The two operations are different.

Comment: @Bruno I took your code, fixed the compile errors (undeclared variable n) changed the input to `int tab[]= {1,1};` the output was `1     added 1     added`

Comment: oh yes when I changed the definition I removed the test after the while, I reintroduced it

Comment: @bruno ok, down vote removed, yours is the best answer

Comment: @PaulSanders what do you mean ? `new Node(..)` return a new Node instance

Comment: @PaulSanders I don't understand, my constructor is just `Node::Node(int d) : next(0), data(d) {}`

Comment: @PaulSanders I added a newline between the '{' and the '}' is case it was less readable when all was on the same line

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt. Look for the existing data *first* then add if not present (no change there from existing code)

```
bool add(Node*& head, int data) {
    Node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp) {
        if (tmp->data == data)
            return false; // data already present
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    Node *n = new Node;
    n->data = data;
    n->next = 0;

    if (!head) {
        head = n;
    }
    else {
        Node *tmp = head;
        while(tmp->next)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = n;
    }
    return true; // data added
}
```

Comment: what a bad idea to go through the list 2 times !

Comment: @bruno, very true, i'll leave that improvement to the OP

Answer (score -2):

So I did something like that and it works with the data I have. I suppose it works in general

```
bool add(Node*& head, int data){

Node *n = new Node;
n->data = data;
n->next = 0;

if(!head)
    head = n;
else{
    Node *tmp = head;
    while(tmp->next){
        if(tmp->data == data)
            return false;
        else
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->next = n;
}
};
```

Comment: It needlessly allocates a node even if it is not going to be used.

Comment: True that, my bad. Thanks for noticing it

Comment: It also doesn't find an equal element when it's the last item in the list.

Comment: you do a memory leak